# Spring security - Restricting Authenticated User redirection to Login

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security

After login, when login url is accessed with out logging out, login page is shown, but I do not want the login Page, instead remain on the same page even when login url is accessed from address bar.

Following is my security configuration:

```
<form-login login-page="/loginform.do" authentication-failure-url =     "/loginform.do?error=1" default-target-url="/dashBoard.do" always-use-default-    target="false" />
```

One solution I come across is to redirect page, if the role is not 'ROLE_ANONYMOUS'

```
<sec:authorize ifNotGranted="ROLE_ANONYMOUS">
  <% response.sendRedirect("/mainpage.jsp"); %>
</sec:authorize>
```

But can a similar configuration be done in security configuration file ?

Comment: Not sure if you can do it in a configuration file. I would go with a web Filter, there you can do exactly what you're doing in your JSP, but remains valid for every single url and provides more flexibility.

Comment: Thanks, web filter is was working, but was exploring config file solution.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this with an `HandlerInterceptor` because I dont know a build in solution.

```
import org.springframework.web.util.UrlPathHelper;
...

public class PreventLoginPageForLoggedInUserInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {


    private UrlPathHelper urlPathHelper = new UrlPathHelper();

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
                             HttpServletResponse response,
                             Object handler)
                   throws Exception {

         if (urlPathHelper.getLookupPathForRequest(request).startsWith("/login"))
             && isAuthenticated()) {

            sendRedirect(request, response);
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

     private void sendRedirect(HttpServletRequest request,
                               HttpServletResponse response) {
         response.setStatus(HttpStatus.TEMPORARY_REDIRECT.value());
         response.setHeader("Location", response.encodeRedirectURL(request.getContextPath() + "/"));
    }

    private boolean isAuthenticated() {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        return (authentication != null) 
               && (!authentication instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken)
               && authentication.isAuthenticated()
    }

}
```